# java.io.IOException: Stream closed or Underlying input stream returned zero bytes, while reading character from request.getInputStream()

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, servlets

I have a Servlet which has request ratio around 10,000 request/hour.

In which, I got one of these two exception frequently at same line which is around daily 5 to 6 times but not every time when this Servlet is called.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:205)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
```

or

```
java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:287)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:205)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
```

Both exception occurs at the same line.I don't know why?
Same type of all requests excecuted and get responded successfully.

Here is my code :

```
InputStream ist = request.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ist));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
char[] c = new char[1];
while(in.read(c, 0, 1) == 1)  // Getting exception at this line
{
    sb.append(c[0]);
}
String payload = sb.toString();
```

Note : Streams are properly closed at the end of the code.

Is it because of high request ratio? Give solution/suggestion if you have any.

Comment: The stream is closed. Did you close it?

Comment: No, that is not an issue. Closing of stream is properly handled, which is called at the end of all process.That's why I specially mentioned that I got this exception only 5 to 6 times per day not for all requests.

Comment: Is is possible another thread is accessing this same InputStream?

Comment: No..The Code which I post is the beginning part of `simple servlet(not an async)` where I try to get post data which is bind with request. After getting valid `payload` , it will be processed further but I got this exception before that while reading data.

Comment: most likely the client closed/broke the connection.  networks interruptions happen all the time.

Comment: Hi @DarshanPatel you got this issue resolved. I am also facing the same error all the time in my CXF based restful webservice

Comment: Yeah, it is nothing but network issue in client as @jtahlborn told but I just want to clarify that is there any another issue or not? So, if it is not consistent then no need to worry.

Comment: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes,error increase the timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jtahlborn rightly mentioned in comment,

There is no bug in code. It happens mostly when the client `closed` / `broke` the connection or maybe network `interruption` / `slowness` which you can not control.

Luckily, I have never faced this error again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an error similar to this one, where I received a 'java.io.IOException: Stream closed' (ServletException).
After testing every part of the service separately, I realized that somehow the POST method was getting me the error. I replaced for a GET method and the error was gone.
The case was similar, getting the error once in while (like 4-5 times in an hour for a 30-second-delay request).
Now, after a couple of days, I haven't seen it anymore.